# JmDns.create Does not bind to InetAddess

Tags: java, jmdns

I am running Ubuntu. Trying to create JmDNS service But `JmDNS.create()` Does not bind to ip address.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, You need to create by  `JmDNS.create(InetAddressString)` This will work.